# GROUP BY clause is not displaying rows correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I have an "Answer" database table below:

Answer Table

```
AnswerId SessionId QuestionId Answer
10       AAD       7          A
11       AAD       7          B
12       AAD       7          D
13       AAA       1          A
14       AAC       1          True
```

Now as you can see above there are 3 answers for question 7 in Exam (Session) AAD, there is 1 answer for question 1 in Exam (Session) AAA, and these is 1 answer for question 1 in Exam (Session) AAC.

So When I output the table in php/html, it should display it like this:

```
  Question  Answer

  7         ABD
  1         A
  1         True
```

But the problem is that it is displaying the table in 3 separate rows which I do not want:

```
Question  Answer
7         ABD
7         ABD
7         ABD
1         ATrue
1         ATrue
```

So I am guessing that I have got my GROUP BY CLAUSE incorrect, my question is that what should the GROUP BY Clause be so that it is correct?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT an.SessionId, an.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT( an.Answer
ORDER BY an.Answer
SEPARATOR  ' ' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks
FROM Answer an
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
```

Below I have included the SHOW CREATE TABLES for "Question" and "Answer" Tables:

Question Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Question` (
     `SessionId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     `QuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL,
     `QuestionContent` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
     `NoofAnswers` int(2) NOT NULL,
     `ReplyId` int(1) NOT NULL,
     `QuestionMarks` int(4) NOT NULL,
     `OptionId` int(2) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`SessionId`,`QuestionId`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Answer` (
 `AnswerId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SessionId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `Answer` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AnswerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Below is the "Question" Table rows (I only include SessionId and QuestionId columns as they are relevant for this situation:

```
SessionId QuestionId 
AAA       1
AAC       1
AAD       7
```

The rows in the "Answer" table is at top of this question.

UPDATE: With the query above I get these results (Only including relevant columns):

```
SessionId  QuestionId  Answer
AAA        1           A A        // This row answer should only be "A"
AAC        1           True True  //This row answer should only be "True"
AAD        7           A B D      //This row is fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY` clause. Try this, (*it's a simplified version*)

```
SELECT QuestionID, GROUP_CONCAT(Answer SEPARATOR '')
FROM tableName
GROUP BY SessionID, QuestionID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7047e/1)

Comment: I forgot to paste my GROUP BY CLAUSE in the question. I will test your group by clause, you can have a look at mine if you want

Comment: @user1701484 remove the `an.AnswerId` in your query.

Comment: I have updated the GROUP BY clause but still can't get it to work. AM I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you add the schema of your tables and sample records on it?

Comment: Give me 10 mins, I think I just realised that I don't think I set foriegn keys between the "Question" and "Answer" Tables, would this be the difference?

Comment: I have included a SHOW CREATE TABLE on both the "Question" Table and the "Answer" Table. I also included "Question" Table rows but only included the relevant columns, not all of the columns as they will be irrelevant for this question. If you need more info then just comment to me,

Comment: @user1701484 what are the results if you execute the query above? the one with `GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId`?

Comment: I Included update of query result below, I added 2 extra columns in SELECT statement which I editted my query. I only included relevant columns for the result of the query as no need for you to look through all columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17839/discussion-between-john-woo-and-user1701484)